# OpenIDConnect good practice - keep connection

Tags: authentication, security, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I've been using OIDC for some time now and I'm looking for solution so that my users have to reconnect as rarely as possible, without compromising security. I use both web browser and desktop apps to connect.

I know that I can play with the lifetime of access tokens and refresh tokens, and the number of refresh tokens to be issued. However, when I see what happens with google authentication, I notice that :

- I almost never need to enter my Google credentials again in the browser. I'm pretty much always connected.
- I literally never have to reconnect desktop apps like Google Drive.
  I assume that google would not mess with security. So does anyone know how do they achieve this kind of behaviour ?

BTW, I'm using keycloak as my IAM provider.

Thank you for reading !
Antoine

Answer (score 0):

They all issue a long lived session cookies that they store in your browser, this is how they keep you signed in.

For example, Google achieves single sign-on through their various services by using https://myaccount.google.com/ as its central authorization server and you have a long lived session with that service besides **mail.google.com**, **contacts.google.com** for example.